# error while loading libgtkglext-x11-1.0 libraries

Tags: command-line

```
root@Saurabh-PC:~/Desktop# anydesk
anydesk: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0&searchon=contents) with relevant library inside by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1
```

Also please note that you do not need root rights to run AnyDesk, use rights of ordinary user.